# 0x api: how to set specific receiver address on quote interface?

Tags: 0x

in our project,i wanna specific a address to receive all tx tokens,but i cant find any params about this.
[0xapi quote](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into setting the `takerAdress` parameter? Here’s an example of a request that uses that parameter:  https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote#supplying-a-taker-address

`takerAddress` should be the end user submitting the transaction (i.e. an EOA). Depending on your integration, you might be setting takerAddress to a contract address you were filling from.